# histogram fit for probability density

Tags: fitting, probability-or-statistics, data

I am trying to fit the (probability density) histogram of some data with the exponential function, but I am having difficulties.
My raw data are in file called `datachopped`. They are not 'probability density'. I want to fit the probability density histogram of this data with Exp[-x]. So I use the following command:

```
Histogram[datachopped, Automatic, "PDF", 
 Epilog -> First@Plot[Exp[-x], {x, 0, 4}, PlotStyle -> Red]]
```

This gives me this plot:

[image]

The data is/was [**here**](http://ge.tt/4uGNb4L1/v/0?c)

However, I don't know how well this plot fit, i.e., how to compute the chi-squared, etc. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked at EstimatedDistribution?  It can use maximum likelihood methods which are typically a much better way to fit a distribution than fitting an approximate PDF obtained by binning.  If you go with that, see [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6498/standard-errors-for-maximum-likelihood-estimates-in-finddistributionparameters) for computing standard errors.

Comment: If you need to use the binned data for other reasons, then this is a duplicate of [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/39679/12).  Then errors can be obtained as described [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NonlinearModelFit.html) under details, or using Sjoerd's answer from my previous link.

Comment: So, I used EstimatedDistribution with
dist = EstimatedDistribution[data, ExponentialDistribution[a], 
  ParameterEstimator -> {"MaximumLikelihood", 
    Method -> "FindMaximum"}]

which gave ExponentialDistribution[0.999997]. It looked great. But then,

Show[Histogram[data, Automatic, "ProbabilityDensity"], 
 Plot[PDF[dist, x], {x, 0, 3000}]]

showed nothing on the plot!

DistributionFitTest[data, dist, {"TestDataTable", All}]

gave me Pearson Chi^2 values as Statistics: 121163 and P-value 1.084\times 10^-25972. This means that the exponential distribution is bizarrely off from the data!!!

Comment: It's hard to tell what's going wrong without having the data to test with.  You can consider uploading it somewhere, e.g. http://ge.tt

Comment: Here is the data file: http://ge.tt/4uGNb4L1/v/0?c

Comment: Regarding the plots, maybe you need to change the scale, possibly like `Show[Histogram[data, "Log", "PDF"], 
 ListLinePlot[{Log@#, PDF[dist, #]} & /@ 
   HistogramList[data, "Log", "PDF"][[1]]]]`.

Comment: You have some very large numbers in your dataset.  An exponential distribution is extremely unlikely to produce these.  I believe this is where the problem stems from.

Comment: @Szabolcs, Even if I chop the data say below 4, i.e., datachopped = Select[data, # < 4 &] and follow the above commands for datachopped instead of data, still I get very similar results. I still tend to think that it is not about the big numbers. EstimatedDistribution did find a value for the fit for the ExponentialDistribution. But when I put it back to the test, it fails.

Comment: @b.gatessucks, I am not worried too much about the plots here. The problem is how to fit these data to exponential distribution and then how can I test the fitness using Mathematica. As I mentioned in my comments to Szabolcs, P-value is ridiculously small for the fit Mathematica itself has obtained (and this is the exponential dist is the one people expect to fit these data - so this is not a completely wrong fit for the data to try).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the data has been removed from the repository and I don't believe the question can be answered without it

Comment: @belisarius I seem to be able to open the data repository just fine. Nevertheless, I still agree with closing the question since it is very unlikely to attract attention so long after it was posted.

Comment: @MarcoB Well, I can't access it. Thanks for checking it!

Comment: I was able to obtain the data.  There are 121,163 data values (and none are binned (other than by machine precision).  As @Szabolcs mentions there are some very large numbers.  The mean is nearly exactly 1.0 and the variance is around 137.  If the numbers were from an exponential distribution with mean 1, the variance would be also be 1.0.  Coupled with having so many observations gets one a very small P-value (which doesn't necessarily mean a poor fit).  What constitutes a good fit depends on the objective of fitting a probability density in the first place.  Not a Mathematica question.