# How to fit a Weibull distribution function to histogram with unequal bins?

Tags: fitting, distributions, histograms

Whenever the function "FindDistributionParameter" is used in Wolfram Mathematica, it needs two inputs: raw data and distribution function.

I have a problem where I have have data and I need to use Weibull distribution function, but bins in my histogram are unevenly spaced.

How do I add that information into "FindDistributionParameters" function in order to get a proper fit?

Comment: You can't get there from here with `FindDistributionParameters`.  You'll need to use `LogLikelihood`, `CDF`, and `FindMaximum` and have the counts (rather than relative frequencies).  I think there's an example in this forum but using the log normal distribution.  I'll look for that.

Comment: Take a look at https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/203547/how-to-relate-a-binned-pdf-to-a-pdf-taking-into-account-how-the-data-is-binned/203552#203552.

Comment: Thank you for your answer JImB!

Answer (score 2):

One can't use `FindDistributionParameters` once the data becomes binned. However, one can construct the log of the likelihood function and then use `FindMaximum` as long as you still have the counts.  (The relative frequencies won't do.)

```
(* Generate histogram data with unequal bin widths *)
SeedRandom[12345]
x = RandomVariate[WeibullDistribution[2, 3], 1000];
{borders, counts} = HistogramList[Log[x]];
borders = Exp[borders] // N
(* {0.090718, 0.110803, 0.135335, 0.165299, 0.201897, 0.246597, 0.301194, 0.367879,
    0.449329, 0.548812, 0.67032, 0.818731, 1., 1.2214, 1.49182, 1.82212, 2.22554, 
    2.71828, 3.32012, 4.0552, 4.95303, 6.04965, 7.38906, 9.02501} *)
counts
(* {1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 4, 7, 6, 16, 17, 26, 58, 59, 94, 117, 148, 176, 112, 78, 58, 13, 1} *)

(* Log of the likelihood *)
logL = Sum[counts[[i]] Log[CDF[WeibullDistribution[a, b], borders[[i + 1]]] - 
  CDF[WeibullDistribution[a, b], borders[[i]]]], {i, Length[counts]}];

(* Find maximum likelihood estimates using the default starting values of 1 for both parameters *)
mle = FindMaximum[{logL, a > 0 && b > 0}, {{a, 1}, {b, 1}}]
(* {-2460.29, {a -> 2.0714, b -> 2.9929}} *)

(* Estimates of standard errors *)
cov = -Inverse[(D[logL, {{a, b}, 2}]) /. mle[[2]]];
ase = cov[[1, 1]]^0.5
(* 0.0516358 *)
bse = cov[[2, 2]]^0.5
(* 0.0485239 *)
```